# Special series of story-telling segments, as told by actors; one had a magical whale who befriended a girl

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic

I'm not sure of the series in question, or if it was a "special" of sorts; it was played, on tap, in class during the 1980s as part of story time. The screen focused on actors.  (For some reason I'm seeing a man that looks like Bram from the  **Sharon, Lois & Brams Elephant show** as one of the speakers.) The two stories I remember specifically:

**1)** A story about a girl, narrated by a brown-haired Caucasian women, speaking about a girl, who apparently befriended a magical animal (I'm thinking "Wolf" or "Whale") which her parents didn't like, and sought to kill. The animal told her she would know he was dead (and I remember this specifically) when she saw  "three drops of blood" fall from her handkerchief, but not to worry; they would be together. At the end of the story, a crack opens up in the earth, and draws her in; her mother tries to hold onto her, but is left only holding her hair, I believe, before the crack seals up.

**2)** A second story, narrated by the fellow who looks like Bram, speaks to a boy who would watch other boys play baseball from the fence. The man (I think) narrates this story as though it is one from his own childhood, and he is speaking from memory. When a hitter injures himself, the boy asks "Could I pinch hit?" and though he doesn't make the run, he looks happy. The narrator asked him why, and the boy said "... I played."

Can anyone speak to if this was a series or a video special of some sort, please?